# Gulp @import Ошибка

Tags: css3, gulp-sass

Пытаюсь в scss файл импортировать css файл:

```
@import 'app/libs/fonts';
```

В Gulp выдает предупреждения :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 1, column 8 of /libsass/test.scss:
Including .css files with @import is non-standard behaviour which will be 
removed in future versions of LibSass.
Use a custom importer to maintain this behaviour. Check your implementations 
documentation on how to create a custom importer.
```

В итоге стили не не рабоатют!
Gulp config:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
del = require('del'),
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
cache = require('gulp-cache'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function(){ 
return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.+(sass|scss)') 
    .pipe(sass({ 
        includePaths: [ 
                'app/libs/foundation-sites/scss' 
                      ] 
               })) 
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true })) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) 
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) 
     });
     gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { 
    browserSync({ 
    server: { 
        baseDir: 'app' 
    },
    notify: false 
   });
 });

 gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src([ 
    'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'app/libs/fontawesome/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.min.js'
    //'app/libs/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js')) 
    .pipe(uglify()) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js')); 
  });

 gulp.task('css-libs', ['sass'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/css/libs.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
   });

    gulp.task('img', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/img/**/*') 
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({  
        interlaced: true,
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        use: [pngquant()]
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); 
  });

  gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function() {
gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.+(sass|scss)', ['sass']); 
gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); 
gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);  
});

   gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del.sync('dist');
  });

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'img', 'sass', 'scripts'], function() {

var buildCss = gulp.src([ // Переносим библиотеки в продакшен
    'app/css/main.css',
    'app/css/libs.min.css'
    ])
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))

var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*') // Переносим шрифты в продакшен
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))

var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*') // Переносим скрипты в продакшен
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))

var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html') // Переносим HTML в продакшен
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});
  gulp.task('clear', function (callback) {
  return cache.clearAll();
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все куда проще, они более не поддерживают иморт css. Или конвертируйте css в scss, либо укажите уже к готовому файлу в библиотеке в формате scss. По крайней мере я перекачал библиотеки и подключил scss файлы.

Как вариант использование библиотеки [gulp-cssimport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssimport)

Update: Нашел решение для себя еще одно, при импорте нужно указать расширение файла `.css`

Answer (score 0):

Ваш gulpfile.js у меня  отрабатывает как положено но с путями к файлам правильными.

Исходя из вашего gulpfile.js, файл в котором находится строка 
`@import 'app/libs/fonts';` расположен в каталогe `app/sass/` или вложенных в него каталогах и ваш файл.css находится в папке `app/libs/fonts/`, 
 надо проверить:

- Если sass файл расположен в каталогe `app/sass/` тогда строка импорта
  должна быть такой:
   `@import '../libs/fonts/файл.css';`
- Если sass файл расположен во вложенном каталогe `app/sass/**/` тогда 
  строка импорта должна быть такой: 
  `@import '../../libs/fonts/файл.css';`
- Если файл с импортом расположен по другому пути то    исправляйте
  пути в этом месте:
  `return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.+(sass|scss)')`

Если после этого не заработало пробуйте проделать это:

1. Удали из папки node_modules которая в проекте папку gulp-sass
2. Удали строку gulp-sass из package.json
3. Удали если есть node-sass из package.json
4. Запусти установку `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`

Думаю это должно помочь, но обязательно проверьте пути.